# How can I update custom order fields in the frontend

Tags: custom-field, plugin-craftcommerce

I am struggling with using additional custom order fields. (Added in the Craft Commerce settings at "order fields", in the field layout manager)

I try to update them like this in the checkout process:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">
    <input type="text" name="myCustomField" value="Test123">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Update Custom Field">
</form>
```

But in the Order in the CP, the field stays empty. Do I have to use another `name` for the field, like `fields[myCustomField]` or whatever?

I can update them in the CP, but not from the front-end...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correct, you need to use `fields[customFieldName]` as the input name.

The following form should do it:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">
    <input type="text" name="fields[myCustomField]" value="Test123">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Update Custom Field">
</form>
```

Comment: Sweet! Is there also a way to validate those fields?

Comment: Validation would need to be front end only for now.