# Option and notes fields after cart at checkout for order, not just line items

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, custom-field, ecommerce, order

My client has gift wrapping services but they apply to the entire order, not one single line item.

How would I add notes or custom fields to the entire order, at the shipping stage of checkout? is this possible without a plugin?

I tried to apply notes and giftwrapping options to the first line item by using the commerce/cart/updateLineItem form, on the cart.lineItems.first() but it didn't work. I presume that after the user proceeds to checkout the line Items no longer exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a special product for the gift wrapping and offer to add it to the cart during the checkout process with a separate updateCart form.

As for the notes, you can add a custom field to your order as described in the following: [How can I update custom order fields in the frontend](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13104/how-can-i-update-custom-order-fields-in-the-frontend)

Comment: Two very good answers here! I like the idea of it being a product especially as it makes more of a feature and could show what gift wrapping looks like. (This is for luxury products)

Comment: Yep, lets you add variations and options for different gift wrapping too. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, add a custom field to your orders, let's call it `orderNotes`.

Then, in any `updateCart` form, you can use an input with `name="fields[orderNotes]"` to set the value of that field.

(Line items persist on the cart until the end of checkout.  At that point they become a saved snapshot of those line items on the completed order.)

```html
<form method="POST" >
       {{ getCsrfInput() }}
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">
       <input type="text" name="fields[orderNotes]">
       ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add it to the `cart.lineItems[].options`:

```
<form method="POST" >
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">
    <input type="hidden" name="purchasables[{{ purchasable.id }}][id]" value="{{ purchasable.id }}">
    <input type="number" name="purchasables[{{ purchasable.id }}][qty]">

    // custom option
    <input name="purchasables[{{ purchasable.id }}][options][giftWrapping]" value="YES!">

</form>
```