# Craft Commerce - add additional message during checkout

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

We can add a message to a product while adding it to the cart as per this question here - [Option and notes fields after cart at checkout for order, not just line items](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/option-and-notes-fields-after-cart-at-checkout-for-order-not-just-line-items)

But is there a way to add a message during the actual check out process, before the payment is submitted?  At any stage during the checkout?

If we create a custom field in Commerce > Order Fields, can we add this to the checkout for the customer to fill out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misreading that question - it too is asking about adding a message to a cart, not line items.

The second answer to the question you linked - https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/22777/340 - has what you need - it talks about notes on orders, rather than line items.

This can be done at any point in the order/checkout process - any call to update the cart that supplies a value for that field will result in the data being added.

Looks like the official Commerce docs have info on this here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/update-cart-custom-fields.html

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your help.  I definitely was, I think it was the addToCart that threw me off.  I can see now that you can apply that at any stage during the checkout process and we have the working on the site.